# Comparing infinite dimensional distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given two infinite sequences of rvs $(X_{1},X_{2},...)$ and $(Y_{1},Y_{2},...)$, how can we show $(X_{1},X_{2},...)\stackrel{d}{=}(Y_{1},Y_{2},...)$?

The way I heard is by comparing all their finite dimensional distributions. Is that we how we define "comparing infinite dimensional distributions" or does it follow from a deeper fact like Kolmogorov's extension theorem?

Thank you